# .Net5 SignalR SqlNotification Not Notifying Client

Tags: signalr

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I am developing a .Net 5 SignalR notification that utilizes SQL Notification.  The application is partially working, sending a notification to the client on the first time the page loads.  After some further debugging.  I determined the SendCallNotifications method is called correctly upon each database update, however, the client does not update correctly.  I'm not sure if the problem lies in my javascript, a threading problem since it is set up as a task, or whether there is some type of failure in the pipeline.  Here is my hub code:

```
    public class CallNotificationHub : Hub
{
    //
    //  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0
    //  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0
    //
    private SqlDependency dependency;

    //  public Task OnConnected()
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }


    //[HubMethodName("sendCallNotifications")]
    public async Task SendCallNotifications()
    {
        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Reached", "New SignalR5 Notification", "");

        try
        {
            string connectionString = "connectionstring";
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [TimeEntered], [CallFrom], [CallTo] FROM [dbo].[tbl_Log_InboundTwilioCalls]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dependency.AddCommandDependency(command);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "user", "message");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendEmail sendErrEmail = new SendEmail("SendCallNotifications Error", ex.ToString(), "");
        }
        
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveNotification", "Changed");
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail("Dependency Change", e.Type.ToString(), "");
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {                
            CallNotificationHub nHub = new CallNotificationHub();
            nHub.SendCallNotifications();
        }
    }
```

And here is my javascript.

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/CallNotificationHub").build();

connection.on("RecieveNotification", (result) => {
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = result;
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);

console.log(result);
alert("Changed");
});

connection.start().then(function () {
connection.invoke("SendCallNotifications").catch(err => console.error(err));
}).catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

I don't see any errors in the console, so I am not sure where to look next.  Any help would be appreciated.

I just ran into a new error showing up in the console:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'SendCallNotifications' on the server.
invocationDescriptor.invocationId http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:2259
processIncomingData http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:2371
onreceive http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1923
onmessage http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4728
connect http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4725
connect http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4687
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4649
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4630
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4624
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4620
connect http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:4669
startTransport http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3842
createTransport http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3792
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3411
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3392
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3386
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3382
createTransport http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3745
startInternal http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3665
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3411
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3392
fulfilled http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3383
promise callback*step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3385
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3386
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3382
startInternal http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3596
start http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3480
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3411
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3392
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3386
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3382
start http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:3468
startInternal http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:2036
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1883
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1864
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1858
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1854
startInternal http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:2024
startWithStateTransitions http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:2006
step http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1883
verb http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1864
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1858
__awaiter http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1854
startWithStateTransitions http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1993
start http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js:1989
<anonymous> http://192.168.0.3:61443/js/CallNotification2.js:14
```

CallNotification2.js:15:69

Trying to figure out what this is telling me.  Haven't seen this before.

Comment: i don't think the way you are appending li and setting content is correct

Comment: I think it is correct, but just in case, I took the code out that appends the <li>, however, it doesn't write to the console either nor does it trigger the alert("Changed").  I also moved the email notification to right before the clients are notified and the email notification fires correctly each time.  So it appears to be either in the await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveNotification", "Changed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); or somewhere in the client code.  However, the client code works correctly on the first load.